# VBA to hide and unhide columns based on their dynamic first row value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 2 sheets: `summary` and `ClickHide`.

- `Summary Sheet` contains multiple checkbox forms.  When the checkbox is checked, they return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value in the `ClickHide Sheet`, all in `ROW A`.
- `ClickHideSheet`: Next to these values in `A2:A20`, I attribute a "0" or "1" value to the `TRUE or FALSE` result.  These results go horizontally in  range `B2:BZ45`. On `ClickHide Row 1`, I have formulae to get a result on top of each column.
- In `Summary B1:BZ1` I have copied links to the cells in `ClickHide A1:BZ1`.

**My question**:

> I intend to make the columns in `Summary` to automatically hide when the value in their own row is **not** 0.  (if B1 is not 0, hide column B, otherwise unhide).  The user will interact with the checkboxes, so the macro needs to be triggered every time a checkbox is modified.

I have found code snippets out there, but none of them seem to work.  I'm really bad at VBA, so it could be a simple edit that I'm missing.

I've tried both of these, with no success. Have a look [the following reference](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=79218).

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 80
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = Cells(2, i) = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

This next one I don't really know if it's a VBA code or not.

```
oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
oSheet1 = oSheets.getByName("Sheet1")
oColumns = oSheet1.getColumns()
for i = 0 to 25
   oCol = oColumns.getByIndex(i)
   oCell = oSheet1.getCellByPosition(i,0) 'First row has index 0
   If oCell.Value = 0 Then
      oCol.isVisible = False
   Else
      oCol.isVisible = True
   End If
next i
```

I don't know how to embed a spreadsheet in here, so here are pictures of both sheets, simplified to show an example.

- [Summary Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHa9u.png)
- [ClickHide Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cjqt.png)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To 9
        Set rng = Cells(1, i)
        If rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0 Then
            If rng.Value = 1 Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 1
        Else
            If rng.Value = 0 Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It will work from columns `B` to `I` (columns 2 to 9) on any sheet. Change this number if the columns you need to evaluate changes.

[image]

If you want it to only work on a specific sheet, change the first line to `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` and place it in that specific sheet's module.

EDIT: Revised code, it should potentially run much faster when there are few changes.

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as intended.  For some reason it's pretty slow.  Probably because it's cycling through all columns.

Comment: It's instantaneous in my test sheet. The thing that is probably making it slow, is if you have a lot of recalculations, especially if they are automatic.

Comment: If there's only 1 sheet the macro needs to work on, you might try the suggested approach for that as well, it would probably help speed things up (by not getting triggered on recalculations on other sheets). See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Nickstoy See revised answer, I think it should work a lot faster.

Comment: Yes that does work a lot faster!!   I used `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To 80
        Set rng = Cells(1, i)
        If rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0 Then
            If rng.Value <> 0 Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 1
        Else
            If rng.Value = 0 Then rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

The codes that you posted don't belong to Excel rather it is of openoffice.

Below code will hide columns for the cells(in 1st row) that have values =0.You can include this code at the end of your macro.

```
Public sub Hidecol()
'Count no. of used columns in 1st row
l = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
'Loop through 1st row  1stcolumn till 1st row lastcolumn
For i = 1 To l
'if cell vaue is 0 then hide cell column
If Cells(1, i).Value = 0 Then
Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I've cleared out all my VBA as I was accomplishing nothing.  I have added this in front of your code  Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)    and closed with End Sub

Comment: doesnt seem to trigger or do anything.  I never know where to paste these codes... Sheet, Workbook, module?

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)` only works for change event in the worksheet.You must include it in `Public Sub` module.Goto vba insert a module

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Vegard's answer, and it works well.

I've also applied this script, which seems to run slightly faster, but overall still pretty slow.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


    For Each cell In Range("B1:BZ1")   '**edit if not correct range
        Select Case cell.Value <> 0
            Case False
                cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case True
                cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next cell

    End Sub
```

Comment: Turning off screen updating might speed it up a bit. Place `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the `For` loop and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after it ends.

Comment: Thank you, it did slightly improve.